# How to open url in existing active tab of chromium

Tags: tabs, chromium, kiosk

I have chromium running in kiosk mode, sometime I want to open different url in same existing tab using command, I don't want to open new tab because I want to show something different every other time of day (it would otherwise open hundreds of new tabs after long time). I want to use bash script launched using cron.

Is there some parameter like `chromium --same-tab <URL>` ? Or do I need to do something using xdotool.

I don't want to `killall chromium` because it will for few second show black screen until new instance appears (I have desktop with black background, openbox only).

Comment: All the command line switches of Chrome are available here: https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/

Comment: I hoped to find it there, but didn't find it.

Comment: Then that probably means a command line switch is not available for that specific purpose

Comment: I am using https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/one-tab-only/cdkbmeoilbjdnbaonjnenjdafkgaeabo/related